# How to prevent iOS and macOS from deleting dictionaries when low on free disk space?

Tags: macos, ios, dictionary

The various built in dictionaries are one of my most used and cherished features on both macOS and iOS. Yet both operating systems delete dictionaries without asking when running out of free disk space. So when I want to use them, I have to wait for the download again and again.

How do I prevent macOS and iOS from ever removing my dictionaries?

Comment: What directories have been deleted on MacOS - I don't think it does that

Comment: Totally happens to me all the time with my the dictionaries from my non-default language (English). But I _need_ dictionaries for both languages. I think I'm going to file a bug with [Feedback Assistant](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/new-form-response) and see if it ever gets fixed ever. You might want to do the same.

Comment: I have exactly the same vexing. Maybe we can try to do a chmod on Dictionary files?.. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

That's what I did, waiting for the results:

```
cd /System/Library/AssetsV2/com_apple_MobileAsset_DictionaryServices_dictionaryOSX
sudo chmod -R 555 *.asset
```

Ran on:

```
$ uname -rsv
Darwin 19.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 19.6.0: Tue Jun 21 21:18:39 PDT 2022; root:xnu-6153.141.66~1/RELEASE_X86_64
```

Comment: Dang! Thanks @bmike, that "cd" must have been omitted while I was copy-pasting! :)